# MVVM Command Routing Between Controls

Tags: wpf, mvvm, routed-commands

I currently have a main View with a Button and a ContentPresenter which is bound to a property of the ViewModel which is another View (and associated ViewModel).  Is there way to route a command from the a handler declared in the control loaded in the ContentPresenter?  My reason for this is the main View contains the tool bar and the content presenter has the content.  I am using the Microsoft MVVM template and the generated DelegateCommand class.

```
<Window ...>
   <Button x:Name="btnAction" Command="{Binding ActionCommand}" />
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a command object which is a static object on a class that both the window and the control can see.

```
  public static class MyCommands
  {
     public static RoutedUICommend CoolCommand .....;
  }
```

Then you can bind the control's Command property to the command object, for example:

```
<Button Command="cmd:MyCommands.CoolCommand" />
```

Then you simply need to handle the command binding at the window level using the CommandBinding XAML element.

```
<CommandBinding Command="cmd:MyCommands.CoolCommand" Executed="My_Handler" />
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  Out of curiosity is it a common WPF practice to have a shared command repository for linking stuff together?

Comment: It's not that this is a standard practice for linking stuff together. It's more a common practice for when you need to bind commands to command handlers that don't share bindings in another way. This is basically the same mechanism that the built-in WPF comments used (such as ApplicationCommands).